# How to call a script every time a user logs in (or whenever a session is active)

Tags: php, session

I am trying run a script called `random_post_generator.php` which should execute every time a user is logged in.

I am using this approach as an alternative to cron.

Here is how my session is currently created:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
?>
```

But how do I say - "if session is active, then run this script"?

Comment: that block in the else mean tha session existe and user is logged in so put that script there ??

Comment: @RmidiAyoub - The thing with this is that say for example, I have ` include 'random_post_generator.php';` where you tell me to, I can simply refresh the page, and the query will run again. I just need it to run once, when the user logs in and thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    include 'random_post_generator.php';
}
?>
```

or you can use `require 'random_post_generator.php'`

Comment: Your approach works, it does execute the script upon log in. But, I need the script to only be executed ONCE, and only when a user logs in, how do I do this?

Comment: Do you have POST action on user login?  You can use it in this case.

Comment: Are you reffering to the POST action of the form which logs the user in (if credentials are correct)? A form which is located on `index.php`

Comment: Yes
Also you can include random_post_generator.php in place where credentials are checked

Comment: Ah, true! Works better if I include it where credentials are checked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to find out how to include a script of php (that is located in an outside .php file) inside your current file while using your previous code that checks if a user is logged in:

```
<?php
$root_directory_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    $pathName = $root_directory_path."myScript.php";//I am assuming here
    //the script is located inside the root directory, and not in a sub
    //directory
    require($pathName);
}
?>
```

just remember that whatever php code is inside myScript.php has to have the `<?php ?>` tag surrounding it. Your code does not reuse the `<?php ?>` tag of the "calling" file.

Let me know if that worked for you